# How to find all TODO with a certain tag?

Tags: org-mode

If I wanted a list of all TODO entries with a certain tag, or set of tags, how would I search for them in org-mode?

Comment: Have you looked at http://orgmode.org/org.html#Matching-tags-and-properties ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this interactively type C-c a m 
then type:
tag+TODO="TODO"

replace tag with the one you want to search on.

Comment: You can also use `C-c a M` and search for just "tag".  This will match any un-done TODO state.

Comment: remember to add file to org-tags-view https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/54222/how-to-search-by-tags-in-org-mode