# How to search by tags in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, search, org-tags

Here is a simple file:

```
#+TAGS: math(m) music(u)

* Gödel :math:
* Bach :music:
* Gauss :math:
* Beethoven :music:
* Mozart :music:
```

Then I tried `M-x org-tags-view`

```
Match: +math
```

I expected that Gödel and Gauss will be printed, but instead I get an empty buffer that says:

```
Headlines with TAGS match: +math
Press ‘C-u r’ to search again with new search string
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`org-tags-view` shows matches in *all agenda files*: you have to add this file to your agenda files (at least temporarily). You can do that with <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>: that adds it to the front of the list of agenda files (i.e. to the variable `org-agenda-files`). You can later delete it from the list if you want with <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> (i.e., this will remove the file you're visiting from `org-agenda-files`). But while it's on the list, you can search for tags with `org-tags-view`.

Comment: How to do this using all buffers in a specific directory?

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein You can add a directory to `org-agenda-files`. For that, Org will search files that match `org-agenda-file-regexp` (try to look at their docstrings with `C-h v`)

Comment: Is it possible to use `org-tags-view` for the current buffer that is in the window?

Comment: You can let-bind `org-agenda-files` to the current file around a call to `org-tags-view`.